# Extracting part of an Outlook item

Tags: vba, outlook

I have one Outlook Item which has lots of messages in the body.

Is it possible to extract only the last message? Using Left function maybe?

Example of a body that has two messages (I need to extract just the first message)

```
**From: dot@dot.com.br
To: aw@yahoo.com.br
Subject: Testing

Hi, this is FIRST test.

Thanks.

John Doe
Telephone: 555 21803**



From: dot@dot.com.br
To: aw@yahoo.com.br
Subject: Testing

Hi, this is the SECOND test.

Thanks.

John Doe
Telephone: 555 21803
```

Comment: If you can assign the entire message to a string, you could search for the last occurence of "From: " and make a substring from that position.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetMessageFromMail()

    Dim mi As MailItem
    Dim vaMessages As Variant

    'Get the email item - your method will be different
    Set mi = ActiveInspector.currentItem

    'Split the body into an array. Every time it sees the
    'string 'From:' it creates a new array item
    vaMessages = Split(mi.Body, "From:")

    'The 0th message will be the two asterisks that precede the
    'From: so to get the first message we need the 1 index of
    'our zero based array
    Debug.Print vaMessages(1)

    'Or you could get the last message by using UBound
    Debug.Print vaMessages(UBound(vaMessages))

End Sub
```